# Why am I getting a Subscript Out of Range Error 9 when referencing another Workbook/Worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro (within a Master Workbook) that is getting data from another Workbook/Worksheet using `.value2`.

I've tried different changes, within the code.  I double checked that both workbooks are open.  However, I keep getting the `Subscript out of range (Error 9)`.

```
Sub NielsenScorecard_DataPaste()
    Dim WbNielsenScorecard As Workbook
    Set WbNielsenScorecard = Workbooks("Nielsen Scorecard_Template.xlsm")

    TotalUS_DataPaste
End Sub

Sub TotalUS_DataPaste()

  **Subscript out of range (Error 9)**
    With Workbooks("Power Query - Meijer_Walmart_Total US xAOC.xlsm").Worksheets("PQTotalUS")
        Dim Data(0) As Variant
            'Copy Data Range
            Data(0) = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), "AA2").Value2
    End With

    'Worksheet Code Name within this Workbook 
    With wsTotalUS
        Debug.Print wsTotalUS.Name
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        .Range("A2:AA" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row).ClearContents
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Data(0)))
                .Resize(ColumnSize:=UBound(Data(0), 2)).Value2 = Data(0)
            End With
    End With

End Sub
```

[image: VBA Printscreen]

Comment: double check the spelling of both the workbook and worksheet and that the target workbook is open.

Comment: Is workbook "Power Query Meijer_Walmart_Total US xAOC.xlsm" open?

Comment: @ScottCraner I added a print screen of the workbooks/worksheets.  Everything is open and spelled correctly.. unless I'm completely missing something

Comment: @FaneDuru I added a print screen: yes, "Power Query - Meijer_Walmart_Total US xAOC.xlsm" is open

Comment: In your screen shot there are spaces in `PQ Total US`.  None in your code.  Difference between codename and sheet name.

Comment: Yes, it is, but, as @Darrell H  said, the spelling of the used sheet name is wrong. This is the reason for the raised error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a sheet by its codename, however it is a different format and must be in `ThisWorkbook`.  A drawback is that you cannot reference a sheet in another workbook by its codename.  `Worksheets("PQ Total US").Activate` versus `PQTotalUS.Activate`.  If your goal is to shorten the code and not have to repeat a long name, then another option is to do the following:

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Power Query Meijer_Walmart_Total US xAOC.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("PQ Total US")

With ws1
     'Do something
End with
```